# AutoHotKey infinite while loop

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to create something like this in AutoHotKey?

```
bool isReady = false;
while (!isReady) {
   // Do something here
   isReady = true;
}
```

I tried to experiment with While loop, but it ended with just 1 loop regardless of the condition I give the program. I am currently using Version 1.0.47.06.

I read the documentation here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/While.htm I tried to give the while loop a value of true. But it only executed once. (I was expecting it to loop forever, until I terminate the script).

```
condition := true

while (condition)
{
    MsgBox, condition
}

while (true)
{
    MsgBox, true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, but the `While` command requires version 1.0.48+.

You should update to the latest version of AHK here - http://ahkscript.org/download/

Comment: @George Did this answer solve your problem? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

To create a infinite loop , you can use this syntax:

```
    Loop
    {
      ; Your other code goes here 
    }
```